# Викторина и модуль random

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random,time

start_time = time.monotonic()
correct = 0
q1 = 'The epoch is the point where the time starts, and is platform dependent. For Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC). To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at time.gmtime(0).'
q2 = 'The functions in this module may not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future. The cut-off point in the future is determined by the C library; for 32-bit systems, it is typically in 2038.'
q3 = 'UTC is Coordinated Universal Time (formerly known as Greenwich Mean Time, or GMT). The acronym UTC is not a mistake but a compromise between English and French.'
q4 = 'Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code. When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.'

all_answers = q1,q2,q3,q4


for _ in range(4):
    print(random.choice(all_answers))
    ask = input('T or F? ')
    if ask == 'T':
        print('Correct!, +1')
        correct += 1


    else:
        print('uncorrectly')


print('Результат = ' + str(correct))
print(f'Тест пройден за {int(time.monotonic() - start_time)} секунд')
```

Важно , чтобы вопросы шли в рандомном порядке и не повторялись. Но в моём коде вопросы могут повторяться по 2-3 раза, каким образом можно это исправить?

Comment: Использовать random.shuffle

Answer (score 1):

## Вот так можно:

```
# Формируешь список вопросов:
all_answers = [q1,q2,q3,q4]

#Вариант первый -> Берешь рандомного из "колоды":
while(len(all_ansewrs) != 0):
    print(all_answers.pop(random.randint(0, len(all_answers)-1)))

#Вариант второй -> Замешиваешь "колоду" каждый раз, когда берешь из:
while(len(all_answers) != 0):
    random.shuffle(all_answers)
    print(all_answers.pop())
```

В вашем варианте ви просто печатали из списка случайный елемент (никак не изменяя список при этом):

```
 print(random.choice(all_answers))
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `random.shuffle()` чтобы заранее изменить порядок вопросов.

Значит, вместо вашего

```
all_answers = q1,q2,q3,q4


for _ in range(4):
    print(random.choice(all_answers))
```

примените

```
all_questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4]
random.shuffle(all_questions)

for question in all_questions:
    print(question)
```